# jQuery escaping quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I'm trying to escape quotes in the text I need to change.

The problem is that if I have quotes in #stuff (" or ' in CHANGE1 or CHANGE2) it keeps failing my whole request. Otherwise if I escape it with escapeQuotes() it won't find **"** in my original text.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.escapeQuotes = function() {
    return this.html().replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
  }
})(jQuery);

$("#stuff").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("CHANGE1", "CHANGE2")).escapeQuotes(); 
});
```

Let's say I have this in **#stuff**:

```
    <div id="stuff">
I'm trying to escape this. ALSO I'D LIKE TO ESCAPE THIS: ".
</div>
```

Comment: Your code, as it is, doesn't do anything as the return from `.escapeQuotes()` is not used.

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is?  You only need to escape quote in code, eg `.html("a\"b")` if your string is `a"b` then you don't need to escape the quotes.

Comment: `.replace("a", "b")` will only replace the first.  See .replaceAll or use `/g` regex